# Транзакции при запросах к разным БД

Tags: laravel, транзакции

Вечер добрый!

К одному приложению подключено несколько разных БД.
Настройки у всех аналогичные.

Внутри одной транзакции делаю несколько запросов к таблицам разных БД.
При этом, неважно, как какой БД я сначала делал запрос - результат всегда один: механизм транзакций срабатывает только для БД, установленной по-умолчанию.

Может быть, тут есть, кто встречался с подобной ситуацией?

Все таблицы других БД в InnoDB.
Ко всем таблицам делаю запросы через модели, никаких запросов напрямую.

Пример установки транзакции:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

if (($arResult = $this->businessLayer->createOfficeNumber($arUpdate)) === false) {
      DB::rollBack();
      throw new ApiException("Error CREATE OfficeNumber");
}

if (!$arResult['success']) {
      DB::rollBack();
}

DB::commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow:

Для БД, не установленных по умолчанию, необходимо открывать транзакцию с указанием имени соединения.
Вышеуказанный код должен выглядеть так:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
DB::connection('имя_другого_соединения')->beginTransaction();

if (($arResult = $this->businessLayer->createOfficeNumber($arUpdate)) === false) {
      DB::rollBack();
      DB::connection('имя_другого_соединения')->rollBack();
      throw new ApiException("Error CREATE OfficeNumber");
}

if (!$arResult['success']) {
      DB::rollBack();
      DB::connection('имя_другого_соединения')->rollBack();
}

DB::commit();
DB::connection('имя_другого_соединения')->commit();
```